# Slick grid - Slick.Editors.LongText working as Slick.Editors.Text & remains non-editable due to wrong version of jquery

Tags: slickgrid

I am working with editable slick grid and copied the code from here:

1. [Code](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/gh-pages/examples/example3-editing.html)
2. [Demo Example](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example3-editing.html)

I have included required JS files and the CSS. But when the grid loads, the LongText fields acts as Text field and remains uneditable.

See below image for more information.

[image]

I do not see any JS error on the console. What could be the reason for this behavior??

**Upon further investigation, my friend found out** that the pop-up which shows the textarea, does comes up but the its style is set as `disply:none` . This style is applied to the div which actually shows the pop-up. If we change the style for this div to `diplay:block` I can see the pop-up.

```
element.style {
z-index: 10000;
position: absolute;
background-color: white;
padding: 5px;
border: 3px solid gray;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
top: 489px;
left: 505px;
display: none;
background-position: initial initial;
background-repeat: initial initial;
}
```

**Update:** I just came to know the issue is due to wrong version of jquery being used.  Please check [this link for working example](http://runnable.com/UmGbo1p6ZNFjAAAe/slickgrid-examples-editable-grids):

`problem`: On index.html page, if I change the `jquery version from 1.7 to 1.9`, the pop-up on `description field does not appear`. I am using following CDN for jquery. I cannot switch back to lower version of Jquery as I am using version 1.9 for other purpose in my project.

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`

Comment: Can you post your columns definition please

Comment: @BelowtheRadar: added the column definition.

Comment: you said you included all the js and css used in the demo and copy/paste the code? Did you import /css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css ?

Comment: Is your page accessible online?

Comment: @BelowtheRadar: no, its not accessible. But I have pretty mush used the same code as shown here: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/gh-pages/examples/example3-editing.html . I have updated question to provide some more information. Please relook at the question.

Comment: You have a css conclift, might be z-index or you load wrong version of the css. I recommend you to use this more up-to-date branch https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid

Comment: @BelowtheRadar: Thank you for your suggestions.  I have downloaded the slick grid package using bower (its version 2.1.0). z-index seems to be correct. Only difference I found is `display:block`

Comment: Is it solving your problem?

Comment: @BelowtheRadar: I have updated the question. In my example I am using version 1.9 of jquery which is not supported. Please help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78869/discussion-between-sharpcoder-and-below-the-radar).

Comment: @BelowtheRadar: I am now using latest version of slick grid which solved my problem. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, I am now using [latest version of slick grid](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/releases) (2.2.2 at the time of publishing this answer) which supports jquery 1.9 as well. I must give credit to @BelowTheRadar for his suggestion.